# Installing plugins in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, installation

I'm trying to install a couple of slicing plugins for Eclipse: Indus and Kaveri http://indus.projects.cis.ksu.edu/projects/kaveri.shtml.

Kaveri is a UI interface for Indus. The developers explain that you must download plugin from the website and place it in the plugins folder in ECLIPSE_HOME - which I've done. They also say that Kaveri builds on the Indus plugin, but I can't find any instructions on how to install it. I guessed it would be the same as Kaveri, so I also placed this plugin in the plugins folder.

At this point the software should be installed. But Eclipse doesn't seem to recognise it at all. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Try starting Eclipse with the '-clean' option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't make a difference though :(

Answer (score 1):

I've spoken to the developers, and they said that the plugin requires Eclipse 3.2 and the Groovy Monkey plugin to work.

Answer (score 0):

To get unpacked plugins recognized by eclipse you should move them over to dropins folder. This folder is checked every restart for new plugins.